# what is the diffrence between my best movies and the best movies?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between **"my best movies"** and **"the best movies"**?!

When someone asks you: *What is the best movies you have ever seen?*

Is it true to say, for example:

> One of my best movies I've ever seen ...

or

> One the best movie I've ever seen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say "one of **the** best movies I've ever seen."

If you say "one of *my* best movies I've ever seen", it sounds like you are an actor playing in the film or you are the director... And then, why would you say that? It makes little sense, you see.

By the way, you can also say "one of **my favorite** movies is... ."

Answer (score 0):

"Your best movies" are the best movies you have made or contributed to. For example if you are a film director or an actor.

"Your favorite movies" are the movies you like the most.

"The best movies" are the movies you claim (by whatever criteria you choose) are for some reason the best of all the movies there are.